# JavaScript - Nested function dropping .length of array

Tags: javascript, scope, nested-function

I'm trying to write an app that can record and store keypresses into a variable called "hotkey".  The idea is to create an array of keypresses to define a hotkey of simultaneous keypress inputs and fire actions with them.

The problem is that I keep running into a function scope issue.  From what I understood about function scope, nested functions (in this case anyKey) should have access to all the variables of their parent scope (in this case testFunc()).

I feel I'm missing something major here but I'm not sure what it is.  I know it has to do with the nested functions retaining variables but it seems like how I have it should work.  Any ideas?  Any major concepts I need to self-educate on here?

Thanks in advance.

```
function testFunc() { 
  var hotkey = [];  
    console.log("hotkey length is:"+hotkey.length) //Yields "hotkey length is:0"
  hotkey[0] = "dummy";

  input.addEventListener("keydown", anyKey);

}

function anyKey(ev, txt, hotkey){  //If I don't enter hotkey as a paremeter, I'm notified "hotkey is not defined".  If I _do_ enter it, I get "nested hotkey length is: undefined

console.log("nested hotkey length is:"+hotkey);

let target = ev.currentTarget;
  let tag = target.tagName;
  let char = ev.char || ev.charCode || ev.which;
  log(char, tag);
  let s = String.fromCharCode(char);
  log(s);

/***
The following code, consequentially, doesn't work because hotkey.length isn't defined
***/
        for(i = 0; i <= hotkey.length + 1; i++){
        if (hotkey[i] === undefined || hotkey[i] === "dummy"){
          hotkey[i] = char;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you realize that function `anyKey` is out of scope from `testFunc`? So, any local variable won't be able accessible from the function `anyKey`

Comment: "_nested functions (in this case anyKey) should have access to all the variables of their parent scope (in this case testFunc())_". True, but here `anyKey` is not a nested function of `testFunc()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out `anyKey()` is *not* nested in `testFunc()`, it's just called from within `testFunc()`. That's not enough to share the same scope. Here's an example of a function nested within another that shows them sharing a variable `keyCount` that keeps track of how many times a key is pressed:

```js
function testFunc() {
  let keyCount = {}
  let input = document.getElementById('myInput')
  input.addEventListener("keydown", addCount);
  
  // addCount is nested here
  function addCount(ev) {
    let key = ev.key
    // this functin has access to keyCount because it's nested
    // within testFunc
    keyCount[key] = (keyCount[key] || 0) + 1
    console.log("counts: ", keyCount)
  }
}
testFunc()
```

```html
<input id='myInput' type="text" />
```

It may not be convenient to nest your two functions. Ad alternative is to simply define `hotkey` outside the functions where it will be within the scape of both or rework the logic so only one function needs access to it. For example, your event handler doesn't need to do much logic — it can just figure out what key is pressed and pass that to an object that manages the state.